# How do you unit test Jboss Rules (Drools) rules?

Tags: unit-testing, seam, drools, jboss-rules

I have written a few Drools rules for my Seam application and am wondering how I go about unit testing these.  Does anybody have any sample code that can show me how to go about doing this?

Comment: I have actually figured this out for myself.  Just wanted to contribute the question, and also the answer to the site for anyone else wondering about this.

Comment: so answer your own question. You might get a self-learner badge ;)

Comment: @samuelcarrijo - I meant to, just forgot.  Thanks for the reminder ;)

Comment: Now if you guys could only up vote the answer I can get that badge ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following code to a unit test (JUnit, TestNG, etc):

```
PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();

builder.addPackageFromDrl(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream( "rules.drl")));

PackageBuilderErrors errors = builder.getErrors();

Assert.assertEquals(0, errors.getErrors().length);

RuleBase ruleBase  = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
ruleBase.addPackage(pkg);

StatefullSession session = ruleBase.newStatefulSession(false);

MyFactObject myFact = new MyFactObject();

session.insert(myFact);
session.fireAllRules();
```

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before I can do so ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider some testing 'sugar' with a [Junit Extensions](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions) library - [droolsassert](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert).